# What's the name of this distorted / dirty brush?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

For example in these images, what are the 'dirty spots' brushes applied to them called?

[image]

I am newbie in PS and trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like [Paint splatter brushes](http://designm.ag/resources/500-splatter-brushes-for-photoshop/) to me.

[image]

Some of them are applied directly to the background directly to the background, using the `Brush Tool` (B):

[image]

And some of them are being used as masks over other elements (new layer with the brush, then apply as mask over other elements):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They do not look like brushes at all. It would appear that they were simply loosely masked to create the white edges.

Comment: Thanks I wasnt talking about the edges but the spots in the rest and the > symbol

Comment: Okay, I still don't think it's any particular brush. It's merely a matter of a poorly made mask to show the white. For the chevrons (>) it's just a matter of painting white spot over them. There's no super-secret way.

Comment: The white spots have a name in brush? For searching google. I searched Dirty Brushes but there are not like the spots in the images, Thanks!

Comment: It's just a standard brush... nothing special. Grab **any** brush and paint white spots.